Pixi javascript library - Unable to append canvas
I'm trying to use pixi.js and seem to be falling over at the first hurdle.
I'm using PixiJS - v8.6.4
I've referenced the js into my body
<script src="pixi.js"></script>

I've set up a canvas
<canvas id="pixiCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="background-color: lightcyan"></canvas>

I'm using blazor so calling javascript as follows:
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("drawCircleAndLine", "pixiCanvas");   
    }
}

My drawCircleAndLine function is very simple at the moment:
function drawCircleAndLine(canvasId) {

    // Get the canvas element by its ID
    const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);

    // Create a new PIXI Application
    let app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: canvas.width,
        height: canvas.height,
        antialias: true,
        backgroundColor: 0xEEEEEE
    });

    document.body.appendChild(app.canvas);
}

The last line of my function is what's seems to be causing the library to fall over.
From the pixi.js files it fall over here:
line: 26545
get canvas() {
    return this.renderer.canvas;
}

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'canvas')

Any suggestions?
